# Static variable placement that used at once in code. Local or class member

Tags: c++

What is the better place to declare static variable if I use it in class member once. I can declare it as class member or local variable at class method? What is better for performance or like clean code meaning? For example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  void RunAsMember();
  void RunAsLocal();

private:
  static int RunsMemberCount;
};

int Foo::RunsMemberCount = 0;

void Foo::RunAsMember()
{
  RunsMemberCount++;

  std::cout << "RunAsMember was called " << RunsMemberCount << " time(s) ever." << std::endl;
}

void Foo::RunAsLocal()
{
  static int RunsLocalCount = 0;
  RunsLocalCount++;

  std::cout << "RunAsLocal was called " << RunsLocalCount << " time(s) ever." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Foo> vecFoos(10);

  for (auto & foo : vecFoos)
  {
    foo.RunAsMember();
    foo.RunAsLocal();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Should I use RunAsMember() or RunAsLocal()? What is best practice?

Comment: If you believe in _encapsulation_, you should give the variable the least exposure necessary.

Comment: This is, like, just an opinion. Functions with state variables inside are an abomination. Later on, you might also want to read/reset/save the value or other stuff. So I would always go with a static member.

Comment: There is no general solution to this, so please focus the question on a specific actual situation, with necessary context.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the situation.

If the variable is only used in one function, `RunAsLocal()` is a better choice. Less class member makes easier to read your code.

If the variable is used in more than one function, `RunAsMember()` is your only choice.